# Pass Map/List to XSLT then loop through List/Map and select value

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to do the following.

I need to pass a list or map to an xslt then loop through the map or list and display the values.

The list or map will contain XML. But won't always be the same size.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="*">


    <xsl:variable name="map">


   <Response>
        <result type="xsd:string">
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>

            // loop through value in map/list and display it

            <xsl:copy-of select="firstValueInMap"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="secondValueInMap"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="thirdValueInMap"/>

           <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>
        </result>
    </Response>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Is this possible? I am not too familiar with XSLT

Thanks

Comment: The question only makes sense if you tell us exactly which programming language and data types you use and which XSLT processor. Is the XML contained as a node or as a string? And if all you want to do is output a CDATA section with all the items of the list then why don't you create the data as a string outside of XSLT and simply pass in a string?

Comment: I am using Mule ESB but the list will be a standard Java Array list. The data inside the list will be a list of Strings not nodes.Can be XSLT 1 or XSLT2, supports both.

Comment: So how do you set that variable or parameter? If the XSLT 2 processor you use is Saxon 9 then I think that http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/using-xsl/embedding/jaxp-transformation.html and http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/extensibility/functions/function-result.html suggest that an ArrayList of Strings passed in from Java shows up to XSLT/XPath as a sequence of strings so based on that you should have no problems using simply  `<result><xsl:value-of select="$list-param"/></result>` with e.g. `<xsl:output cdata-section-elements="result"/>`.

Comment: But all such conversion is very much dependent on the XSLT processsor and the exact API used. I have no idea how Mule handles such stuff.